# I can't remove git folder with rm -rf .git on Windows

Tags: git, rm

I want to init git on the main folder `mern` but not on the `frontend` folder, but if I try to remove git folder from `frontend` I still see the `(master)` text, here's what I'm trying:

```
Jim@DESKTOP-NC66H5I MILGW64 ~/Desktop/pro/mern/frontend (master)
$ rm -rf .git

Jim@DESKTOP-NC66H5I MILGW64 ~/Desktop/pro/mern/frontend (master)
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   ../.gitignore
        new file:   ../app.js
        new file:   ../inc/auth.js

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        deleted:    ../Procfile
        modified:   ../app.js
        modified:   ../package.json

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        ./


Jim@DESKTOP-NC66H5I MILGW64 ~/Desktop/pro/mern/frontend (master)
```

You see, when using `rm -rf .git` I can still see `(master)` which means git folder is not deleted? what is this mean?

Newbie here, please help

Comment: It seems the root of the repository is `~/Desktop/pro/mern`. Run `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` to find the root and remove `.git` there. You may have initialized both `mern` and `mern/frontend` as repositories. If so, the `master` you see now is the `master` of `mern`.

Comment: Nothing is changing, is this correct? https://pastebin.com/raw/RzLcRubk @ElpieKay yeah, I think I did that, so I don't want a git inside another git, if I removed the frontend git, then why I can read (master)?

Comment: In a newly initialized Git repository, even if you haven't added any file or made any commit, `master` is the default candidate branch.

Comment: I'm following this tutorial: https://youtu.be/5PaUiPyBDJY?t=509 so you think I can just move on even when I see "master" on the `frontend`?

Comment: If `mern` is the root and it does not have any nested repositories, you can always see `master` in any of its sub-folders.